# Bootstrap navbar dropdown randomly stops working, starts working on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar (version 3.3.7 - code shown below) on all pages of my ROR webapp. It has two dropdowns that work great most of the time, but quite often (about 10-15% of the time) they will just randomly stop working.

Sometimes all it takes is a quick page refresh to set things straight, and other times it takes hopping around to multiple different pages (or refreshing multiple times) to make it work again - there seems to be no definitive pattern. While refreshing the page a few times isn't the end of the world, it's obviously not ideal for end users. Any tips?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <span class="navbar-brand"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></span>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Add", add_new_object_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Cards", cards_show_path %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Stuff<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Extra Resources", extra_resources_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Preferences", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Contact", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "About", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
**<!-- this area (both above and below) is where it stops working sometimes -->**
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Teacher Tools<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Verifications" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Error Classification", new_correction_storage_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- TODO: not sure where to put the search bar currently! -->
      <!-- defining the top padding with class="top-search" is maybe sub-optimal -->
      <form class="form-inline float-xs-right top-search">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Input a word or phrase">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Langification</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```